# Activerecord Multiple Condition in :all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have this Challenge, Would love to get all courses that match a particular department id and match a particular course year. the former is achieved, but having issues achieving the latter.

```
#course.rb
has_and_belongs_to_many :departments

#department.rb
has_and_belongs_to_many :courses
```

[edit]

```
#student.rb
belongs_to :department
has_many :courses
```

Have this so far

```
## Fetch Courses that Match that studentdept
@coursedept = Course.all(:include => :departments , :conditions => ["departments.id = ? and Courses.year = ? " , studentdept,courseyear]
```

The above returns an empty resultset.
Without the Course Criteria, it works.

How best do i fit in the course Criteria there. have tried various variants

Answer (score 0):

Rails has this functionality built in.  Assuming your has_and_belongs_to_many join table is setup properly, you can get a departments courses like this:

```
courses = studentdept.courses
```

and courses for a specific year like this:

```
courses = studentdept.courses.where(:year => courseyear)
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer.I only have a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship between Courses and Departments, and a has_many between students and Courses

Comment: What does your student model look like? Please update your question accordingly... student was not mentioned.

Comment: Edited my Question to include the student model